# Extended URLs created using multisite feature not loading CSS/JS

Tags: multisite

My .htaccess configuration is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

`wp-config` file is as follows

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com.au');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

sub folder URL is as follows  http://www.example.com.au/support/

Can you please suggest what changes needs to be done so that  JS/CSS files are loaded in path based sub sites ?  Version used is 4.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `apache` configuration file , we had `wp_security.conf` which was enabled.This configuration file contains ACLs to deny `.htaccess` from ALL. On commenting the ACL entry , `CSS/JS` are loading fine in extended `multisite` URL.